# Click is not working in IE11 in Windows 10 for selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Click operation in selenium is not working in IE11 in windows 10.

Issue is that, click event is not listed in event listeners in DOM.

Tried with other alternatives like actions and java script executer but no luck. 
Last option tried with getting the coordinates and do mouse press & release actions through Robot class, but some how this approach is not good. Can someone suggest is there any other alternative?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). We cannot help you with code we cannot see. Update your question with a [mcve] that replicates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show error (message), which you are receiving?

Also you can try:

```
sendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

for this button.

Comment: I am not getting any error, in console it shows that the button is clicked.. but in reality the action is not performed as the event is not listed in Listeners for IE.